# Microsoft Sql Server not fetching the records with Where Condition using java

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm able to print all records with simple query as `Select * from table_name;` but when i'm using with `Where` clause,it is giving no rows found,in my table column index is 7,Please help me how to solve this issue.

```
select * from TABLE_NAME (nolock) where CUSTOMERID=765432345;
```

Please provide reason,why it is happening,but i've tried with another query to get Customer id from customer table,then it is working fine same like below code.

**Java Code is:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;    

public class SqlServerDB {

    public static final String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://ip:PORT;DatabaseName=<db name>";
    public static final String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    static String userName = "xxxxxxxxx";
    static String password = "xxxxxxxxx";
    public static Connection conn;
    static ResultSet query;
    static String status;
    static Statement statement;

    public static Connection connect() {

        System.out.println("Sql Server Database Connection Started");
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, password);
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Database Connection is established");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Database is not Connected");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conn;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        conn = connect();
        // Create Statement
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        String sqlQ = "select * from TABLE_NAME (nolock) where CUSTOMERID=765432345";
        // Execute the query
        query = statement.executeQuery(sqlQ);

        if(query.next()) {
            if(query.getString("INVOICE")!=null) {
                System.out.println(status=query.getString("INVOICE"));  
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No rows Returned");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are there any records with CUSTOMERID=765432345 in the table?

Comment: Yes,Single record only.

Comment: try closing the connection in the end `conn.close()`

Comment: Is INVOICE column present in the table?

Comment: Does the invoice column for customer #765432345 contain a NULL?

Comment: Invoice column exists in database table,don't know why it is not fetching records.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is case sensitive?

Try

```
select * from table_name (nolock) where CUSTOMERID=765432345;
```

Comment: Also with select * from table_name (nolock) where customerid=765432345; ?

Comment: Is CUSTOMERID defined as String?